# How to replace the Javadoc in MethodDeclaration?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, abstract-syntax-tree

We know that, from MethodDeclaration `m`, we can get `Javadoc d = m.getJavadoc();`. Now I construct a new Javadoc so I want to replace the old

```
public void replaceJavadoc(ICompilationUnit unit,Javadoc newDoc) {
  // can't use m.setJavadoc(newDoc) although it indeed have this method
}
```

It's easy to get `MethodDeclaration` from `ICompilationUnit`. Also we can get `CompilationUnit`,`ASTRewrite`, but I can't figure out how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

i found this respense in the net possible it wil give you an idé an help you:

```
AST ast = cu.getAST();
cu.recordModifications();
Javadoc jc = ast.newJavadoc();
TagElement tag = ast.newTagElement();
TextElement te = ast.newTextElement();
tag.fragments().add(te);
te.setText("ici il faut insérer le commentaire aproprier ");
jc.tags().add(tag);
tag = ast.newTagElement();
tag.setTagName(TagElement.TAG_AUTHOR);
tag.fragments().add(ast.newSimpleName("ici il faut chercher le nom de l'auteur"));
jc.tags().add(tag);
```

it is to creat au java doc.
I am searching the same. I want to add comments and java doc in a java source générated automatiquely do you have an idé please?
If you want we will change ower emails,for more speed
good luck

Comment: i can create javadoc,but i can't change the whole javadoc of method

Comment: @danzen  
can you show me how have you proceded to generate java doc?